# Is it possible to select and upload multiple files at one time in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I'm writing a form to select and upload multiple files at one time. This seems to be a pretty straight forward task in FF and Chrome but appears to be a limitation in IE 7.

Are there any suggested workarounds?

This is an internal application for my company's intranet and IE is the default browser. There is now word on upgrading to IE 8 or 9, does anybody know if this would make a difference?

What is happening under the hood which which makes IE different from FF and Chrome in this instance? I know this is a lot but specifically to selecting and uploading files.

Thanks,
Russell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE 7 currently does not (and probably never will) implement the `multiple` option for file upload `input` elements which Chrome/FF/Safari/Opera implement. Therefore there is no script/HTML support for receiving multiple files with a single HTML input.

The only option you have for multiple file upload with a single input object is either a Flash-based solution or an Active X control. Alternatively you can create multiple file `input` elements using javascript.

Comment: When you say never will are you talking only about IE7 or IE in general?

Comment: IE7 in particular. As of 2011 IE8/IE9 do not implement the `multiple` option on the `input` element of type `file`. Perhaps IE10 will. Don't hold your breath.

Comment: Fast-Forward in Time: This is supported form IE10: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple