# how to fix the multiple files upload bug in INTERNET EXPLORER

Tags: internet-explorer, image-uploading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to select and upload multiple files at one time in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207388/is-it-possible-to-select-and-upload-multiple-files-at-one-time-in-internet-explo)

i have a php script to upload multiple images and save image names in database everything was going well until i tried to upload multiple images with internet explorer 8 .I cant select more then one image at a time in internet explorer i cant figure out why is internet explorer is not allowing me to upload multiple images 
i use following html tags to upload multiple images

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple />
```

i think internet explorer does not allow to upload multiple images i need to know how to fix this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 does not support `multiple`. This has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207388/is-it-possible-to-select-and-upload-multiple-files-at-one-time-in-internet-explo).

Comment: i never workd with flash can you tel how can i go about to fix this problem pls i dont want to give multiple upload button it will spoil the aesthetics of page

Comment: @sohaan Have a look at http://www.uploadify.com/