# jquery.form.js didn't work in IE when upload image

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, image-uploading

I use `jquery.form.js(version 3.18)` in my page to upload an image.It works well in FF and Chrome, but not in IE.

In IE the image can be uploaded successfully but i can't get the json return from the server and IE says "access denied". p.s. jquery version is v1.5.1. can anyone help??

Here is my js code:

```
var options = {
    target: '#bar_img_info',
    url: 'dealUploadImg.jsp',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(msg){
    $('#bar_img_info').html(msg);
    }
};

$("#uploadForm").ajaxSubmit(options);
```

Here is my html:

```
<label>Bar Image：</label>
<input type="file" name="bar_img" value="" id="bar_img"/> <strong style="color: red;"    
    id="bar_img_info"></strong><br />
<a href="javascript:dealUploadImg();" class="btn">upload</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're using `AJAX` upload that is in Internet Explorer 8 does not support `multiple file upload`. This has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207388/is-it-possible-to-select-and-upload-multiple-files-at-one-time-in-internet-explo).