# Upload image not display the in IE Browser Using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, html, css, file-upload

I am uploading image files using jQuery but whenever I upload any selected image. For this, I need to Priview  display the Image in IE browser. But Firefox and Chrome Supported  Following is set of functions .

### My Code

```
<Script>
function previewImages(input) { 
    $('#ImagePreview').html('');
       var fileList = input.files;      
        var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);           
            $('#ImagePreview').append('<a href="#" class="remove"></a><img src="' + objectUrl + '" class="img-polaroid" style="height:70px;width:70px;">');
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
        }
}

  <h1>Upload Image</h1>
  <div class="form_scpop" >
    <form action="" method="get">
       <input type ="file" onchange="previewImages(this);" multiple/>
      <input name="" type="" id="image_alt" class="input_txt" />
      <div id="ImagePreview" ></div>
       <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="closeimgwindow()">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Try to improve your question, it makes no sense.

Comment: `createObjectURL` is not supported in IE 8

Comment: @DC_ my Problem when i browse upload the Image not dispaly the IE Bowser..

Comment: @darshanags...then which one support tell me please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `files` property is not supported for `<input type ="file" multiple>` on IE8 and IE9. Only HTML5 compliant browsers support it. Update to IE 10 and try your code.

```
var fileList = input.files;    
//fileList is undefined in IE 8 and IE 9
```

**Update**

IE8/IE9 do not implement the multiple option on the input element of type (no way to do that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207388/is-it-possible-to-select-and-upload-multiple-files-at-one-time-in-internet-explo)). Try removing multiple option if possible and testing your code. Otherwise you will have to implement file upload via AJAX for older IE. Updating to IE10 browser is easier.

Comment: @Users568109...Thanks Users568 given response. now am install to IE10 then will check

Comment: @Users568109..am getting this error.. Access Denied. Resource access is restricted for cross-origin URL

Comment: @Users568109...i want display all version in IE what u have to do..plase help me.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is upload the image to your server into a temporary folder via Ajax, and then send the url (generated randomly to avoid collisions) back to the window to display. When the user clicks save, copy it over (or reupload) to where you intended it to be.

This would be your ideal cross-browser solution or fallback because older IE's do not have proper support for what you are doing.